# Write value based on number of rows

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write a 'batch' value in each row of column A in my spreadsheet, depending on the number of rows which have data.

For example, if there are 12000 rows which contain data in say column B, the batch value in Col A needs to be set to 1 for the first 1000 rows, 2 for the next 1000 rows etc etc.

I was using this, but I need to manually edit the script after checking the number of rows with data...

```
Sub AddBatchNos()
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A1000").Value = "1"
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1001:A2000").Value = "2"
    etc.etc.
End Sub
```

Is there a way of scripting this so I don't need to manually edit each time?

Comment: You could use a variable and then build the range string with it...

Comment: So, I managed to find the number of rows with this

LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

But have no idea how to build the range string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddBatchNumbers()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'reference your sheet.
    
    Dim LastRow As Long 'find last used data row in column B
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Const AmountOfRows As Long = 1000 'how many rows should be in one group
    
    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 1 To (LastRow \ AmountOfRows) + IIf(LastRow Mod AmountOfRows <> 0, 1, 0)
        ws.Range("A" & (iRow - 1) * AmountOfRows + 1, "A" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Min((iRow) * AmountOfRows, LastRow)).Value = iRow
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Note that `LastRow \ AmountOfRows` is not a normal division `/` but an **integer division** `\`. So the result is always the integer part of the division.

Comment: Thank you SO SO much Pᴇʜ! I would not have got there in a month of Sundays.. You're an absolute star! Stay safe.